# Trigger to replace HtmlBody on EmailMessage being overwritten by native SF logic?

Tags: apex, trigger, emailmessage

We have written a trigger on the EmailMessage object that searches the HtmlBody of any newly inserted record for a static String. If found, Everything from the index of this string to the end of the HtmlBody gets dropped and we replace the HtmlBody value with the remainder. This is working with the exception of emails that have inline images or some other form of inline content that SF must detach and store as an appended Document. In these cases, the EmailMessage HtmlBody content appears to not be affected after flowing through the trigger logic.

Our suspicion is that the trigger is working correctly, but that some native SF process further downstream that separates out the inline content is overwriting the truncated HtmlBody that we are writing. We have attempted Before and After Triggers and even moving the logic into a Process Builder that calls the trigger in an attempt to fire the code as late in the process as possible. We have also researched placing the function to replace the HtmlBody into a future method that the trigger calls, but due to the restrictions that an EmailMessages Status places on an edit we arrived at the conclusion that this could not work reliably.

Has anyone else run into this issue and could possibly provide some guidance or a workaround you used?

Trigger code (which works fine without in-line images) is here:

```
public class VEmailMessageTriggerHandler {

public void beforeInsert(List<EmailMessage> newList){

    for (EmailMessage curEmail : newList){

                if (String.isBlank(curEmail.HtmlBody)==false){
                    String newBody = '';
                    String emailBody = curEmail.HtmlBody;
                    Integer startIndex = emailBody.IndexOf('<<Some delimiter here>>');
                    if (startIndex != -1){
                        newBody = emailBody.left(startIndex);
                        Integer divIndex = newBody.lastIndexOf('<div');
                        curEmail.HtmlBody = newBody + '</body></html>';
                    }
                }

                if (String.isBlank(curEmail.TextBody)==false){
                    String newBody = '';
                    String emailBody = curEmail.TextBody;
                    Integer startIndex = emailBody.indexOf('<<Some delimiter here>>');
                    if (startIndex != -1){
                        newBody = emailBody.left(startIndex);
                        curEmail.TextBody = newBody;
                    }
                } 

        }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you please add the code so we can take a look?.Thanks